# python - cursor not writing to list using input from a dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, cursor

I have a dictionary where each key holds a list of values. I want to loop through a cursor object (qSPAD) looking for each value in the dict keys items and writing the items found to a csv file for each key if an item is found.

```
import csv
import arcpy
import os

dict = {1:[431, 122, 761], 2:[1,5921, 314, 91, 18], 3:[16, 12], 4:[1]}

for k, v in dict.items():
    name = "coQ" + str(k) + ".csv"
    cPath = r"C:\Path"
    coQ = os.path.join(cPath, name)
    with open(coQ, mode = 'w') as company_file:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(qSPAD, ["SPADID", "AddressLookup"]) as rows:
            for row in rows:
                if row[0] in v:
                    company_file.write(row[0], ": ", row[1])
    company_file.close()
```

I want the SPADID value matches an item in the values of a key, I want to write the SPADID and corresponding address to a CSV. So if the first three values in rows were 122, Address A; 81, Address B; 91, Address C

a csv file titled `coQ1.csv` would contain:

```
SPADID: AddressLookup
122: Address A
```

and then a csv file titled `coQ2.csv` would contain:

```
SPADID: AddressLookup
91: Address C
```

However, the dict actually holds 100 keys and the output I got was 100 blank csv files. I would like to see if a value is found in the qSPAD that matches a key's items value and if so writes it to a csv in the format given above for that key in the dict (notice the csv name is based on the key value). If a value is not found in qSPAD, no csv is written for that key (hence the if clause).

Comment: if you use `with open(...) as ...` then you don't need `close()` because it automatically close file when you leave `with ...`

Comment: simply use `print()` to see what you have in variables - probably you don't have correct values and it never goes to `if row[0] in v:`  and doesn't run `write()`

Comment: Are you expecting numbers or strings in your row?  `1` and `"1"` is not the same thing. If strings, try `dict = {1:["431", "122", "761"], 2....` or better still, change it to `if int(row[0])...`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I found a new way to access the dict and write it to a file without needing the cursor. Now I just need to figure out how to write each item in the dict to a new line.